# The exterior differential $d:\Omega^r(M)\to \Omega^r(M)$ defines a fibrewise linear mapping over the exterior bundle $\bigwedge^rT^\star M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional smooth manifold and $E=\bigwedge^rT^\star M$ be the vector bundle of $r$-forms in $M$. The *smooth $r$-forms* in $M$ constitutes the vector space smooth sections of $E$:
$$\Omega^r(M)=\Gamma(E).$$
I was wondering if the exterior differential $d:\Omega^r(M)\to\Omega^{r+1}(M)$ defines a fibrewise $\mathbb R$-linear mapping $d_x:E_x\to E_x$ for every $x\in M$. However, I am not able to convince myself that this is the case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exterior derivative is not a fiber-wise map but a differential operator. If it were a fiber-wise linear map, then for any form $\phi\in\Omega^r(M)$ and any point $x\in M$, $\phi(x)=0$ would imply $d\phi(x)=0$ and this is not true. Similarly, coming from a fiber-wise map would imply that for any smooth function $f$, one would have $d(f\phi)=fd\phi$ which is not true either.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what does fiber even mean in this context? For example, when $r=0$ so that $\Omega^0(M)$ are just smooth functions, which smooth functions on $M$ form the fiber of some point $x\in M$?

Comment: Smooth functions on $M$ are sections of the trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb R$, so in this case the fiber over each $x\in M$ is $\mathbb R$. For $r>0$ the fiber in question is the space $\Lambda^r(T_xM)^*$, the space of $k$-linear alternating maps $(T_xM)^k\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, $d$ does take preserves fibers (trivially, by not touching the base point), but on each fiber it doesn't act as a linear map (e.g. as you said, a function vanishing at a point doesn't mean its derivative vanishes).

Comment: What is true is that $d$ maps sections to sections. But it does not admit a fiber-wise interpretation, since $d\phi(x)$ does not only depend on $\phi(x)$ but also on first derivatives on $\phi$ in that point.

Comment: I see, so fiber-wise means only needing data at a point, not locally. Thanks!